# Using NPOI to open Excel worksheet with pivot chart produces XML error

Tags: c#, excel, pivot, npoi

I have 4 sheets in an excel, the 4th sheet has the data which referenced in the other 3 sheets to populate a pivot table.

1st one is chart sheet which contains pivot chart.

2nd sheet contains pivot table which is used as data table for pivot chart in 1st sheet.

3rd sheet contains pivot table which is used as data table for pivot chart in 1st sheet.

4th sheet contains data table which is used as source for pivot table in 2nd and 3rd sheet.

When I fill data in 4th sheet, other 3 sheets (1st, 2nd & 3rd) doesn't appear in output excel document. Also when I open document it opens in recovery mode. It gives alert with following lines:

From the code I try to update the data in the 4th sheet from the database and pivot table should get reflected based on the data I write on the 4th sheet.

[image]

[image]

Sheet1
[image]
Sheet2
[image]
Sheet3
[image]
Sheet4
[image]